# Can I access AWS Parameter store from Lightsail instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-lightsail, amazon-systems-manager

I have a spring boot server deployed in ec2 which uses Parameter store in System manager to keep the application secrets.

I want to deploy the same now on AWS Lightsail instance.

Please help if this is possible. if yes, how to do it.

Comment: Yes you can - this question is too openended.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to assign an IAM Role to an Amazon Lightsail instance. Therefore, you would need to use credentials from an IAM User, and store those credentials on the Lightsail instance by using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command. Then, any software that uses an AWS SDK will automatically use those credentials to access AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but not through `instance roles` (lightsale instances do not support roles). Instead you have to [setup AWS credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html) on the Lightsail instance as you would do on your local linux workstation.